# can not load image from xcassets by using code, but xib can

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, xcasset

Previous developer using `R.swift` to load resources.

And I delete it from Cocoapods, then I using

```
let image = UIImage.init(named: "testimage")
```

to load image from xcassets, and it return `nil`.

And I load testimage in xib, it works.

I have no idea why I can't load resources from xcassets by using code.

[xcassets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKFXm.jpg)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK8zR.jpg)

[ib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5A24.jpg)

[imageLiteral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i7Ke.jpg)

Comment: So the filename is literally `testimage` with no file extension?

Comment: Should work without extension if the file is in the assets.

Comment: Only if the file is `.png`.

Comment: Not only. I have pdf-s.

Comment: Not according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init).

Comment: Orz, please provide a screenshot of your assets in Xcode, and give a full code snippet of how you load and use it.

Comment: trojanfoe, please read the docs carefully.

Comment: @battlmonstr Here are codes and images.

Comment: @trojanfoe There are all png.

Comment: @OrzHan OK cool.  Then I would suspect that the missing `1x` image version is the cause.

Comment: @trojanfoe I add 1x, and result still nil.

Comment: @OrzHan OK, it's starting to sound like the assets are not in the main bundle. Is there anything unusual about your app WRT bundles?

Comment: Did you try this- Remove the asset named "testimage", make sure even IB doesn't show it. clean build and then add back the asset.

Comment: @trojanfoe Nothing unusual , I add a new xcassets file and add some png inside, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma I can make sure there is only one set "testimage" in my xcassets and bundle.When I remove testimage in xcassets and nothing shows in IB.

Comment: Ok, just giving suggestions here, try this - cmd+shift+m opens media library, shows all the media in project, and from there you can drag an image in your code. It creates an ImageLiteral. Does that show up the image? If there are 3 images namely 1x, 2x, 3x, it will drag all three images, and you can keep just one.

Comment: trojanfoe gives a good suggestion. Could you post a screenshot of how you bundle looks like after the build (look in Products - Open in finder)? does it have the assets in a standard location?

Comment: do you use several xcasset?

Comment: @antonioyaphiar only one.

Comment: have you set that image to uimageview?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma I can see testimage in  cmd+shift+m, but when I drag that in my code and run ,it crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageNameInAssets")
```

Comment: There is no different between UIImage(named: "testimage") and UIImage.init(named: "testimage").

Comment: I agree. This will not solve the problem, as Orz Han stated, the answer is equivalent to the code used by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check Your assests file - make sure your given image name is same as store in assests..

second way..

either You can use the image literal easily...

let image = image literal (select Your image)

Comment: Doesn't  work ,I use image literal to load testImage, it crash.

Comment: can you show crash error here? or you can try change your image..in all image same things happen or only one image?